# Sorting properties with negative integers

Tags: mysql, sorting, symfony, orm, dql

I want to sort an addresses query result with the following properties:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(length=10)
 */
private $block;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(length=10)
 */
private $stairs;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(length=10)
 */
private $floor;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(length=10)
 */
private $door;
```

from a `Property` entity.

So I do in the associated class (community):

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Property",
 *     mappedBy="community", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"block" = "ASC", "stairs" = "ASC", "floor" = "ASC", "door" = "ASC"})
 */
private $properties;
```

As you can see, the properties are not integers, so it seems that they are sorted always as strings.

When it have to sort negative numbers, the result is not logic. E.g.

```
logic blocks sorting: -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, ...
sorting result      : -1, -2, -3, 0, 1, ...
```

The problem would be resolved just changing the properties types to integers, but I need to give the option to get a string, instead of an integer. E.g. *Block: A1*, or just *A*.

The only thing I can imagine to solve it is detecting the `-` symbol as a negative sign when there is an integer after it. But there has to be a better way to achieve this behavior. Any idea?

Comment: If it is really important to control the sort order and have readable values then consider adding blockSort,floorSort etc integer columns.  You can do some majic to set the values more or less automatically.

Comment: @Cerad - I achieved it by doing what you said. Thanks